# Trying to make a triangle made of borders to stop expanding at 1200px

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, border, css-shapes

i wonder if anyone can help, easiest way to show it is the temporary url here: http://norsk-kulturhus-nettverk.a.heltblank.no/

It is the top image. The grey triangle should always follow the image size. Anyone got some tips?

Edit: 
Tried this:

```
.content-type-homepage .grid-section-article-wide .grid-rte {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 20vw solid rgba(242,242,242, 1); 
    border-right: 100vw solid transparent; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for answering, edited the question. Do you understand my problem? should i be more spesific? have tried so many variations by now

Comment: I think the image should be `position: absolute;` which you already have, and the grey triangle should be `position: relative;` and be put inside the images div. this way you can give the grey triangle a width and height of 100%, which will adjust to the images width/height.

Comment: Im not a 100% sure this works thats why i didnt post it as an answer

Comment: Please check this link:-https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Comment: please make an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as you link is "temporary". Your question will be obsolete once you change your page.

Comment: @web-tiki That is a solid point, didn't think about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a media query which finds when the browser hits a certain size and then starts to change the `border` property.

I have tested this on the URL you gave above and it seems to be working.

```
.content-type-homepage .grid-section-article-wide .grid-rte {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 20vw solid rgba(242,242,242, 1); 
    border-right: 100vw solid transparent; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    z-index: 99;
}

@media (min-width:1200px) {
    .content-type-homepage .grid-section-article-wide .grid-rte {
        border-right: 1200px solid transparent;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your css edited. Just replace the `100vw` by the value you need

```
.content-type-homepage .grid-section-article-wide .grid-rte {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 20vw solid rgba(242,242,242, 1); 
    border-right: 1200px solid transparent; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for smaller screen sizes, the border is supposed to be as wide as the image, so a fixed border-width won't work.

Comment: Yes thanks, tried that earlier also. Just figuerd out i can do:

    @media(min-width:1200px){
    .content-type-homepage .grid-section-article-wide .grid-rte { border-right: 1200px solid transparent; }
}

Comment: So that solved it if it isn't bad practice or anything :)

Comment: @kristofferberntsen so just completely missed my answer with what you said you did in the end? :( boooo :P

Comment: @Stewartside Saw that now, crazy. Had a  lecture today at the school on the bootstrap grid subject, so i learned it just when i posted. Not trying to take credit for your answer, thanks for the help :)